# Delphi XE5 Firemonkey - Problema ao compilar aplicação em Application Store

Tags: android, delphi, ios, firemonkey

0
down vote
favorite

Bom dia, desenvolvi uma aplicação Multi-Device para Android e IOS, porém estou com um problema quando compilo minha aplicação no modo Application Store para distribuir no google play.

Algumas funcionalidades que funcionam perfeitamente no modo Debuger, deixam de funcionar quando compilo minha aplicação utilizando o modo "Application Store".

Exemplo de algumas funções que deixaram de funcionar:

A minha função de CheckInternet, assim como o meu servidor Datasnap, a minha aplicação mobile(Android) não consegue se conectar com o servidor, desta forma retornando a seguinte mensagem: socket access denied.

A segui está função que me referi.

```
function CheckInternet : boolean;

begin

result:=false;

try dm.IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 2000;

dm.IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 2000;

dm.IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;

dm.IdTCPClient1.Host := 'google.com';

dm.IdTCPClient1.Connect;

dm.IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;

result:=true;

except

result:=false;

end;

end;
```

Será que o problema é devido eu estar instalando um APK no meu celular no modo Application Store? Sendo que o correto seria a submissão do APk na Google Play e depois o download do mesmo?

São apenas hipóteses que estou levantando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Descobri o que era o problema.
Solução: Adicione no androidManifest.xml

a seguinte permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

PS. Por mais que no delphi em uses permissions esteja marcado ela não está sendo adicionada no AndroidManifest.xml, quando compilado para distribuição.

Comment: +1, não se esqueça de marcar sua própria resposta como correta! Assim facilita a outros usuários encontrar o caminho!